# Ionic app won't log in Xcode

Tags: ios, angularjs, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

Running an Ionic app that works fine on browser and used to work on Xcode simulator and iPhones. I'm watching the log file and something strange is happening.

Once I hit 'Login' on my app, it freezes and here is the output:

```js
Mar 12 15:03:21 C02QJA6VG8WP SpringBoard[37882]: Weekly asset update check did fire (force=NO)
Mar 12 15:03:21 C02QJA6VG8WP SpringBoard[37882]: Beginning check for asset updates (force: 0
Mar 12 15:03:21 C02QJA6VG8WP SpringBoard[37882]: Did not complete check for asset updates (force: 0, isVoiceOverRunning: 0
Mar 12 15:03:22 C02QJA6VG8WP assertiond[37886]: assertion failed: 14F1605 13C75: assertiond + 12188 [8CF1968D-3466-38B7-B225-3F6F5B64C552]: 0x1
Mar 12 15:03:23 --- last message repeated 3 times ---
Mar 12 15:03:23 C02QJA6VG8WP kbd[37935]: table drop: 101
Mar 12 15:03:31 C02QJA6VG8WP assertiond[37886]: assertion failed: 14F1605 13C75: assertiond + 12188 [8CF1968D-3466-38B7-B225-3F6F5B64C552]: 0x1
Mar 12 15:03:31 --- last message repeated 4 times ---
Mar 12 15:03:31 C02QJA6VG8WP assertiond[37886]: Could not create or rename power assertion for <BKNewProcess: 0x7fd0bac01930; com.ionicframework.sameboat491544; pid: 37934; hostpid: -1>: 0xe00002c9
Mar 12 15:03:31 C02QJA6VG8WP assertiond[37886]: assertion failed: 14F1605 13C75: assertiond + 12188 [8CF1968D-3466-38B7-B225-3F6F5B64C552]: 0x1
Mar 12 15:03:40 C02QJA6VG8WP lsd[37908]: LaunchServices: Currently 0 installed placeholders: (
 )
Mar 12 15:03:53 C02QJA6VG8WP mstreamd[37871]: (Note ) PS: Media stream daemon stopping.
Mar 12 15:03:53 C02QJA6VG8WP mstreamd[37871]: (Note ) AS: <MSIOSAlbumSharingDaemon: 0x7f9c42f07b20>: Shared Streams daemon has shut down.
Mar 12 15:03:53 C02QJA6VG8WP mstreamd[37871]: (Warn ) mstreamd: mstreamd shutting down.
Mar 12 15:04:11 C02QJA6VG8WP ids_simd[37874]: (Error) IDSSimulatorSupport: <IDSSimSupportLocalServer.m __68-[IDSSimSupportLocalServer setNetworkSimulation:enabled:completion:]_block_invoke:561> message send of data {
     ControlCmd = SetNetSimulationEnabledCmd;
     Enabled = 0;
     ServiceName = "com.apple.private.alloy.sockpuppet.classd";
 } failed with error Error Domain=com.apple.idssimualtorsupport.errors Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc34e2027e0 {Error Domain=NSMachErrorDomain Code=268435459 "(ipc/send) invalid destination port"}}
Mar 12 15:04:11 C02QJA6VG8WP companionappd[37879]: (Error) WatchKit: <SPTransport.m __67-[SPTransport service:account:identifier:didSendWithSuccess:error:]_block_invoke:430> __67-[SPTransport service:account:identifier:didSendWithSuccess:error:]_block_invoke identifier (B67A5D73-36B1-4B1C-B7EF-952300B137C6), serviceName ((null)), success: 0 error, domain: com.apple.identityservices.error, code: 23
Mar 12 15:04:11 C02QJA6VG8WP companionappd[37879]: (Error) WatchKit: <SPCompanionAppServer.m __75-[SPCompanionAppServer sendProtobuf:sender:timeOut:allowInsecureTransport:]_block_invoke:900> sendProtobuf failed, error : Error Domain=com.apple.identityservices.error Code=23 "Timed out" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Timed out, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd5722058e0 {Error Domain=com.apple.ids.idssenderrordomain Code=12 "(null)"}}
Mar 12 15:04:11 C02QJA6VG8WP sharingd[37884]: 15:04:11.601 : Failed to send SDURLSessionProxy startup message, error Error Domain=com.apple.identityservices.error Code=23 "Timed out" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Timed out, NSUnderlyingError=0x7feb4c913460 {Error Domain=com.apple.ids.idssenderrordomain Code=12 "(null)"}}
Mar 12 15:04:11 C02QJA6VG8WP companionappd[37879]: (Error) WatchKit: <SPTransport.m __67-[SPTransport service:account:identifier:didSendWithSuccess:error:]_block_invoke:430> __67-[SPTransport service:account:identifier:didSendWithSuccess:error:]_block_invoke identifier (E24D19D0-9B54-4A4A-8261-0E12C329B3D9), serviceName ((null)), success: 0 error, domain: com.apple.identityservices.error, code: 23
Mar 12 15:04:11 C02QJA6VG8WP companionappd[37879]: (Error) WatchKit: <SPCompanionAppServer.m __75-[SPCompanionAppServer sendProtobuf:sender:timeOut:allowInsecureTransport:]_block_invoke:900> sendProtobuf failed, error : Error Domain=com.apple.identityservices.error Code=23 "Timed out" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Timed out, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd572205490 {Error Domain=com.apple.ids.idssenderrordomain Code=12 "(null)"}}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Cordova plugin I was using is not compatible with the latest version of cordova-ios. I had to manually remove my platforms/ios directory and recreate it.

`ionic platform add ios@3.9.2`

`ionic build ios`

The plugin I was using was https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/NativePageTransitions